# Starting protractor execution from a selenium session

Tags: selenium, protractor, browser-automation

How can we use protractor with an existing selenium browser session rather than always create a new one. If I have started up a selenium browser session, run some tests in there, and exported the session ID into the environment conf file in protractor or in some other way made it available, it would be nice to be able to configure protractor in the normal way (e.g. using an option in the protractor configuration file) to access this session.

I would need to start a protractor execution in the middle of a selenium execution, do some test, and come back to selenium execution. Something like pseudo-code snippet would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to session id from the launched browser. You should be able to get it from the http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html. So let's say this session id is '12345', you have two options, you could pass it as a command line or via the configuration file.

### command line

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --seleniumSessionId=12345
```

### configuration file

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  seleniumSessionId: '12345',
  ...
}
```

After you have set the selenium session id, you should be able to use the browser session. An example of this being exercised is: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/scripts/driverProviderAttachSession.js

If you would like to read more about it, I also have a medium post about this feature that I might have worked on: https://medium.com/@cnishina/attaching-a-protractor-test-to-an-existing-selenium-session-931196936ae2

Comment: This certainly helps. But how would I pass a dynamic selenium session id in Protractor conf file.

Comment: See the driver provider attach session file. It's in there. It makes a http request to the selenium server and parses out the session. Also launches Protractor via command line.